# How to Skip the login password prompt if not entered

Tags: python, fabric

How to Skip the login password prompt if not entered or password is wrong..
I have Below python fabric code.. which works fine but stucks with wrong passwords..

```
import sys
from fabric.api import *
env.skip_bad_hosts=True
env.command_timeout=60
env.user = 'test'
env.shell = "/bin/sh -c"
env.warn_only = True
env.password = 'mypass'
def read_hosts():
    env.hosts = [line.strip() for line in sys.stdin.readlines()]

def cyberark():
  with settings(warn_only=True):
        output=sudo("/monitor.sh",shell=False)
```

When i run it, it stands there only until i break it manually...

```
[pc-karn] Executing task 'cyberark'
[pc-karn] sudo: /monitor.sh
[pc-karn] Login password for 'test':
```

Is there anyway to set the env where if the password given wrong with 2 consecutive sequence and it will go to the next host in line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this parameters -

```
with settings(abort_on_prompts=True):
```

This parameter terminate the program when prompt the user for input. You can read about it [here](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.11/usage/env.html#abort-on-prompts).

I don't know if this solve your problem, as far as i know Fabric what you are looking for is not possible, but at least you know your program always terminate, and can fix the passwords issue.

Comment: This i tested and it terminate the entire program and loop exits.

Comment: I think that with parallel it should continue with the other hosts - http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.11/usage/parallel.html

Answer (score 0):

When I want to dodge a password prompt but continue my script on fail, I use `abort_on_prompts=True` and catch the `SystemExit` exception that is raised by abort_on_prompt.

```
try : 
  with settings(abort_on_prompts=True):
    output=sudo("/monitor.sh",shell=False)
except SystemExit as se :
  print "What I want to do when it fails"
```